# Columns alias for *

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to set a column alias with use of `SELECT * FROM table_name`?

e.g.:

- this query return every columns

```
SELECT id as table_name_id, name as table_name_id, description as table_name_id FROM table_name
```

- obviously can be written in a more convenient way like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

But there is some way to set the **same table prefix** to all columns results? something like `SELECT * as prifix_ FROM table_name` ?

Thank you!

Comment: Just so that it was said: It's considered better practice to name all columns you want instead of using *

Comment: Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: Thank you, good answers.